# My tkinter countdown function's custom parameters won't work; says it's missing required positional arguments

Tags: python, function, tkinter, parameters, countdown

I'm making a "clicks per second" benchmark minigame for a class project.

In the project requirements, I must write about a specific function that has sequencing, selection, and iteration. It also must be called at least twice in my program.

I want to write about my countdown function, however, I have to alter it to be able to be reused in multiple parts of my code if I want to call on it more than once.

The way my countdown function works is that it updates a specific label every second. But that means that the countdown function only can work for that specific label.

I basically wanted to be able to call on the countdown function to alter any label and not just a specific one. To do that I tried giving the function a set of parameters that specify the label that the countdown would be altering, the text that it would alter, the next frame it would go to after the timer was up, and the amount of seconds it would count down from.

Answer (score 2):

In version 3 of the `countdown()` function you do a `label.after(1000, countdown, seconds-1)` which schedules it to be called again in 1000 milliseconds and passed *one* parameter with the value `seconds-1`. However you need to pass it *all* the arguments each time and you can do that by putting them in a tuple — so you need to do something along these lines:

```
label.after(1000, countdown, (label, nextframe, timertext, seconds-1))
```

(I don't really know what values you want to pass on subsequent calls, this above is just to give you the general idea.)

Here's some documentation of the [`after()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) method — note the last parameter is *`*args`* which indicates it should be some kind of a sequence such as a `list` or `tuple`.